# JSP & Spring Security: redirect is working correct, but without login

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp, spring-security

I'm implementing Spring Security for Spring Boot project.

The problem is: if I use Spring Security configuration like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    public SecurityConfiguration(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().
                 antMatchers("/index", "/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/error")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/CarRentalServlet", true)
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Logic for Controller is:

```
@Controller
public class CarRentalController {
    final OrderRepository orderRepository;
    final VehicleRepository vehicleRepository;
    private final CommandFactory commandFactory;

    public CarRentalController(OrderRepository orderRepository, VehicleRepository vehicleRepository, CommandFactory commandFactory) {
        this.orderRepository = orderRepository;
        this.vehicleRepository = vehicleRepository;
        this.commandFactory = commandFactory;
    }

    @GetMapping("/{view}")
    public String viewMapping(@PathVariable String view) {
        return view;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/CarRentalServlet" }, method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
    public ModelAndView getCommand(@RequestParam(required = false) String command,
                                   HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res,
                                   HttpSession session,
    @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false, defaultValue = "0") Integer page
    ) throws ServletException, IOException {

        Page<Vehicle> vehiclePage = vehicleRepository.findAll(new PageRequest(page, 2, new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "dailyPrice")));

        session.setAttribute("number", vehiclePage.getNumber());
        session.setAttribute("totalPages", vehiclePage.getTotalPages());
        session.setAttribute("totalElements", vehiclePage.getTotalElements());
        session.setAttribute("size", vehiclePage.getSize());
        session.setAttribute("data",vehiclePage.getContent());

        session.setAttribute("orderList", orderRepository.findAll());
        session.setAttribute("vehicleList", vehicleRepository.findAll());
        return commandFactory.getCommand(command).execute(req, res, session);
    }
}
```

And `login.jspx` file as jsp form:

```
                   <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                        <div class="login-panel panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title"><fmt:message key="login.paneltitle" /></h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <form role="form" name="loginForm" method="POST" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="command" value="logInCommand"/>
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <fmt:message key="login.label.login" var="loginValue" />
                                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="${loginValue}" name="username" type="text" autofocus=""/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <fmt:message key="login.label.password" var="passwordValue" />
                                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="${passwordValue}" name="password" type="password" value=""/>
                                        </div>

                                        <fmt:message key="login.button.login" var="loginButtonValue" />
                                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" value="${loginButtonValue}" />
                                    </fieldset>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Another jsp form as `index.jsp`:

```
<div class="navbar-default navbar-static-side" role="navigation">
                    <div class="sidebar-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                            <c:if test="${!empty sessionScope.userName}">
                                <li>
                                    <form name="makeOrderButton" method="post" action="CarRentalServlet">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="command" value="makeOrderButtonCommand"/>
                                        <a href="" onclick="parentNode.submit();
                                                return false;">
                                            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-fw"></i>
                                            <fmt:message key="index.button.makeOrder" />
                                        </a>
                                    </form>
                                </li>
                                <c:if test="${sessionScope.userTypeID == 1}">
                                    <li>
                                        <form name="adminZoneButton" method="post" action="CarRentalServlet">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="command" value="adminZoneButtonCommand"/>
                                            <a href="" onclick="parentNode.submit();
                                                    return false;">
                                                <i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i>
                                                <fmt:message key="index.button.adminZone" />
                                            </a>
                                        </form>
                                    </li>
                                </c:if>
                            </c:if>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- /#side-menu -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
                </div>
```

it redirects me to the correct endpoint `/CarRentalServlet`, but login isn't working at all.

For example, if I don't use `SecurityConfiguration` class, but I'll modify my jsp file like:

`action="CarRentalServlet"` instead of `action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login"` and `name="login"` instead of `name="username"`

it works as expected and login is working, but in this case I don't use Spring Security.

Can someone suggest me how to fix Spring Security configuration or JSP form to make login work as it works without Spring Security.

Comment: Try to move all the `antmatchers().permitAll()` to the bottom of your `.methods()` chain that you have in `configure` method. I'm thinking that `.antMatchers("/index", "/").permitAll()` might be matching your URL extension.

Comment: Thanks, Victor, for trying to help me. If I correctly understand you, I need to swap `.anyRequest().authenticated()` with `.antMatchers("/index", "/").permitAll()`. So I've tested it and as result I see login page if I specify `localhost:8080`. After I enter login and password it redirects me to the correct `/CarRentalServlet` endpoint, but still without login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because of usage `<c:if test="${!empty sessionScope.userName}">` and `<c:if test="${sessionScope.userTypeID == 1}">` in jsp files.

To fix it, I've used [authorize tag](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-taglibs#authorize). So I've changed to `<sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">` and `<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN')">` accordingly.